# Mac OSX upgrade Adobe Flash Player, download stops

Tags: mac, macos, adobe-flash, adobe

I am on Yosemite 10.10.1. For some reason (maybe corrupted initial download) the 1.2MB installer stops at around 30% (34%, 35% or 36%) downloading the full installer.

Comment: Google Chrome and Firefox both work on my iMac, even though Yosemite doesn't, so they probably come with Adobe Flash already installed.

Comment: @JohnIrby They do not.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I spent some time why but I just gave up. Here is my workaround and I hope it will help others. The workaround is to download the offline installer from this page http://www.adobe.com/products/flashplayer/distribution3.html. Download the "DMG Installer (for System Administrators)" and install. After installing restart Safari for example and verify from http://www.adobe.com/uk/software/flash/about/ that you have installed.

Comment: Yup, that's the standard workaround - trouble is, that distribution page moves around, goes on & offline at will, & can be a $%^&* to try find right when you need it ;)